# Save matplotlib pcolormesh output to file

Tags: matplotlib

How to save `pcolormesh` output (a `QuadMesh`) to file?
My figure looks like this.

[image: Figure]

And the axes's children are the following.

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fca1e4a7b20>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fca1e4a7d30>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fca1e4d0b20>,
 <matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh at 0x7fca1e063f40>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7fca1e486890>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7fca1e4869b0>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7fca1e486ad0>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7fca1e486bf0>,
 <matplotlib.axis.XAxis at 0x7fca1e486830>,
 <matplotlib.axis.YAxis at 0x7fca1e4870d0>,
 Text(0.5, 1.0, ''),
 Text(0.0, 1.0, ''),
 Text(1.0, 1.0, ''),
 <matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x7fca1e487310>,
 <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x7fca1e4a5840>]
```

I want to save `<matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh at 0x7fca1e063f40>` to file.

## Hacking it through

```
quad_mesh = ax.get_children()[3]
face_colors = quad_mesh.get_facecolors()  # 90601 x 4 numpy array
```

These 90k (301^2) `quad_mesh._facecolors` values are put in place following `quad_mesh._coordinates`.
So, I just need to reshape them correctly and convert them into an image.

```
face_colors_reshaped = face_colors.reshape((301, 301, 4))
face_colors_reshaped_8 = (face_colors_reshaped * 255).astype(np.uint8)
im = Image.fromarray(face_colors_reshaped_8).transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
im.save('quad_mesh.png')
```

So, I did manage… I just wonder if there was now a better way.

Moreover, the code written above needs to be executed **after** the figure has been rendered, or nothing will come out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ax.pcolormesh you supply C, which maps to the colors via norm and cmap (see https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html).

Here is an example to do this manually:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

C = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(301, 301))

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-1, vmax=1)
C_norm = norm(C)
viridis = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
C_color = (viridis(C_norm) * 255).astype(np.uint8)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(C_color)
```